# Proving independence of card draws (with replacement).

Tags: probability, independence

So, to prove independence of two events x and y, you have to prove that

$$
    P(x \cap y) = P_x(x)P_y(y)
$$

which makes great sense to me, but in practice I can't get it to work. I KNOW that two card draws, with replacement, are independent, but here's an example: given that $P_x(1) = P_y(1)$ if $P_x$ is the probability of drawing some value, say an Ace, 1 time out of 2 and $P_y$ is the probability of drawing a different value, say a Two, 1 time out of 2.

So, here's my math so far, given two card draws:

$$
P_x(1) = P_y(1) = 2(4/52)(48/52)
$$
$$
P_xy(1 \cap 1) = 2(4/52)^2
$$

But obviously here $P_x(1)^2 \neq P_xy(1 \cap 1)$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  They are not independent events.

Comment: How so? They must be with replacement, right?

If I draw one card, place it on the deck, shuffle the deck, and draw another card, those are not independent events?

Comment: Because the events are not "an ace on the first draw" and "a two on the second draw".  They are "one ace and a non-ace in any order" and "one two and a non-two in any order."

Comment: Doesn't the equation I wrote above for drawing one of each card ($P_x_y(1,1) = 2(4/52)^2$) accurately represent the probability of drawing an ace and a two in any order? And doesn't $P_x(1)$ accurately represent the chance to draw one ace and one non ace in any order? I'm drawing two cards either way, so are you saying the event of drawing just one ace (out of two cards) is not independent of the event of drawing just one two (out of two cards)? I'm having trouble processing this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying.  The calculations are correct and they show the events are not independent.  This is not unexpected because the number of aces you draw will affect the probability of drawing just one deuce.

Comment: Even with replacement? Somehow this is baffling to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event of drawing exactly $1$ ace in $2$ draws (with replacement), and that of drawing exactly $1$ deuce in the *same* two draws are *not* independent events.   The number of aces you draw will affect the probability of drawing just one deuce.

$$\begin{array}{rc|ccc|c} P_{X,Y}(x,y)& & & x & & P_Y(y)
\\ &  & 0 & 1 & 2 
\\ \hline & 0 & \frac{121}{169} & \frac{22}{169} & \frac 1{169} & \tfrac {144}{169}
\\ y & 1 & \frac {22}{169} & \frac{2}{169} & 0 & \frac {24}{169}
\\ & 2 & \frac 1{169} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{169}
\\ \hline P_X(x) & & \frac{144}{169}&\frac {24}{169} & \frac 1{169}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the events get $\{AD\}$ (in that order) and  get $\{A = 1\cap D = 1\}$ in two draws, where $A,D$ are the number of aces and deuces (twos).

Case 1. $AD$
What is the probability of drawing an $A$ and then a $D$?
$$P(AD) = P(A)P(D|A) = \frac{4}{52}\frac{4}{52} = P(A)P(D).$$
So they are independent.

Case 2. In two draws, $\{A =1, D = 1\}$
$$P(A=1,D=1) = 2\frac{4}{52}\frac{4}{52}.$$

Clearly $P(A = 1) = P(D = 1)$, and so in two draws
$$P(A = 1) = \binom{2}{1}\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^1\left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^1.$$
So
$$P(A = 1, D = 1) \neq P(A = 1)P(D = 1).$$

Comment: Conceptually though, how does this make sense? If I draw a card, shuffle it back in, and draw another card, shouldn't the second draw be independent of the first? Even if I stop at two draws?

Comment: @bakester14 If I tell you that you drew an Ace on the first draw, then you have ruled out many cases where you get $D$ on the first draw, despite the fact that you still have a $4/52$ chance of drawing a $D$ on the second draw.

Comment: Wow. When you put it that way it's so simple and clear to me some how. Thanks for working with me on it.

Comment: @bakester14 No problem. Consider giving respondents a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.